# Same Vue.js component in two browser tabs make <select> mirror its selected values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue app, using vue-router and a few components rendered in x-templates. In one of those markup templates I have a < select > object. When I open this page in two separate tabs in the same browser session, changed selections in one tab in that  is mirrored in the other tab. I first thought it was the data and methods, but then I added a completely vanilla < select > with a few < option > in it, no bindings, data, event handlers or anything - and it behaves the same! When I select an option in one tab, it selects the same in the other. It is the same for other < select > objects in the same app.

I can't explain it. What am I missing? Do I need to maintain sessions to avoid this? If so, how?

Edit: It is now apparent to me that *all* objects behave the same, and are mirrored between the sessions. This has to be by-design, but how do I do to separate it with a good pattern in Vue.js?

App.js

```
Vue.use(VueRouter)

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: "/",
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: "start",
      component: Start,
    },
    {
      path: '/character/view/:guid',
      name: "character.view",
      component: ViewCharacter,
    }
  ]
})

new Vue({
  router,
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      baseUri: "/"
    }
  },
  computed: {
  }
})
```

HTML

```
<html>
....
<script type="text/x-template" id="template-character-sheet">
<div>
  <select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</script>
...
<script src="/components/ViewCharacter.js"></script>
<script src="/components/App.js"></script>
...
</html>
```

ViewCharacter.js (pieces)

```
const ViewCharacter = {
    template: "#template-character-sheet",
    components: {
      "navigation": Navigation
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        properties: values,
        .......
      }
    },
    computed: {
      current_stability: function() {
        return this.rules.stability_levels.filter(o => o.level == this.character.stability)[0];
      },
      .......
    },
.......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Untested]

I think your problem is having the same `:key` in both of your `<select>`, Try adding a generated key to resolve the issue.

Docs: https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/key-attribute.html

Comment: Well, yes - I mean, they are not separate objects - they are the same object in the app, just showing two times - each in a different browser tab. So, I can't even use the userid as key, because the userid will be the same in both browser tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Brain meltdown. This was me forgetting browser-sync was running in the toolchain to serve the content. Switched to serve, and the problem obviously disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this behavior by setting Browsersync's `ghostmode` option in webpack.mix.js (or wherever you've initialized the script).

From [the docs](https://browsersync.io/docs/options#option-ghostMode):

```
// Here you can disable/enable each feature individually
ghostMode: {
    clicks: true,
    forms: true,
    scroll: false
}

// Or switch them all off in one go
ghostMode: false
```